# Is $f \equiv 1$ the only normalized solution of $f(x) = \frac 1x \int_0^x f(t) dt$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f \in L^1(0,1)$ be non-negative a.e. and such that
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) dx = 1.
$$
Assume that
$$
f(x) = \frac 1x \int_0^x f(t), \quad x \in (0,1)
$$
a.e.

Is $f \equiv 1$ a unique (up to an equivalence class) function satisfying above assumptions? Or there are some other ones?

Comment: It's the only continuous solution. If $f$ is continuous at $x$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and, for $x\ne 0$, $f'(x)=0$. On the other hand, it seems to me we can easily rule out Cantor function behavior.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, this is true. I was able to obtain that. Do you know what happens when we do not assume continuity?

Comment: @xen: but $f\in L^1$ and the identity $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(x)\,dx $ imply that $f$ is a.e. continuous.

Comment: Why only a.e continuous? Clearly $f$ is continuous everywhere.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I think I finally got it. I thought that the problem is that $x \mapsto \frac 1x \int_0^x f(t) dt$ is not in $W^{1,1}(0,1)$, but we do not need that. We can just observe that $x \mapsto \frac 1x \int_0^x f(t) dt$ belongs to $W^{1,1}(a,1)$ for every $a \in (0,1)$, and obtain $f = 1$ on every $(a,1)$. Correct?

Comment: @xen: correct, that approach works for sure.

Comment: @zhw.: $ f $ is only a.e. equal to a continuous function because the OP explicitly stated that
$$
\forall_{\text{a.e.}} x \in (0,1): \qquad
f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_{(0,x]} f ~ \mathrm{d}{\mu}.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f \in L^1(0, 1)$ and 
\begin{align}
F(x) = \int^x_0 f(t)\ dt
\end{align}
then
$F$ is absolutely continuous and $F$ is differentiable a.e. where $F'=f$. Next, observe
\begin{align}
f'(x) = \frac{f(x)x- \int^x_0 f(t)\ dt}{x^2} = \frac{f(x)x-xf(x)}{x^2}=0 \ \ \text{ a.e.}
\end{align}
Combining everything, we have that $f\equiv$ const  since $f$is continuous. Lastly $f(1) = \int^1_0 f(t)\ dt =1$.

Edit: It should be noted that $f$ is **locally** absolutely continuous on $(0, 1)$ since $F$ is absolutely continuous and $\frac{1}{x}$ is also absolutely continuous. Moreover, since we know $f'\equiv 0$ a.e. then by the Fundamental theorem of calculus, we have that
\begin{align}
f(1)-f(x) = \int^1_x f'(t)\ dt =0. 
\end{align}

Comment: Why is $f$ continuous? Even so, being continuous everywhere and having $f' = 0$ a.e. isn't enough to conclude it is constant; a counterexample is the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Comment: @arkeet The key is the absolute continuity.

Comment: @arkeet I realize I was vague about it at first. I have edited the post.

Comment: I think I finally understand. But what do you mean by $1/x$ is absolutely continuous (I think there is no "standard" definition of absolute continuity on open intervals)? If $x \mapsto 1/x \in W^{1,1}(0,1)$, then this is not true. However, $x \mapsto 1/x \in W^{1,1}(a,1)$ for every $0 < a < 1$, and then indeed $x \mapsto x F(x) \in W^{1,1}(a,1)$, which implies $f \in W^{1,1}(a,1)$.

Comment: What I meant was for every $[a, b] \subset (0, 1)$ the fundamental theorem of calculus holds.

Comment: Oh, ok. Great. Now it is clear.

Comment: But you wrote $1/x$ is absolutely continuous. Certainly it's not on $(0,1).$ So you should make that clear in your answer.

Comment: Again, $1/x$ is absolutely continuous on $[a, b]\subset (0, 1)$ for every $a, b$.

Comment: We can actually avoid the notion of absolute continuity. By basic measure theory, the function $ g: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} $ defined by
$$
\forall x \in (0,1): \qquad
g(x) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \frac{1}{x} \int_{(0,x]} f ~ \mathrm{d}{\mu}
$$
is continuous. Clearly, $ f \stackrel{\text{ae}}{=} g $. Next, for any fixed $ a \in (0,1) $, note that
$$
\forall x \in (0,1): \qquad
x g(x) = a g(a) + \int_{a}^{x} g(t) ~ \mathrm{d}{t}.
$$
By the FTC, $ g $ is thus differentiable on $ (0,1) $, and $ x g'(x) = 0 $ for all $ x \in (0,1) $. Therefore, $ g = 1_{(0,1)} $.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

For $x\ne0$,$$xf(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt,$$ so that by differentiation

$$xf'(x)+f(x)=f(x)$$ or  $$f'(x)=0.$$

---

If we assume $f$ piecewise constant, in a constant interval $[x_k,x_{k+1})$,

$$\frac1x\int_0^xf(x)dx=\frac1x\int_0^{x_k}f(x)dx+\frac1x\int_{x_k}^xf(x)dx=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}f_j(x_{j+1}-x_j)+f_k(x-x_k)}x=f_k.$$

As you can check by induction, the only solution is $f_k=1$.

Comment: (Already said by Ted Shifrin)

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but why $f' = 0$ implies $f = c$? We should have $f \in W^{1,1}$. I know that $x \mapsto xf(x) \in W^{1,1}$, but why $f \in W^{1,1}$?

Comment: @xen: sorry, this is well above my head.